# Displaying text below react slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to display some text below the react slick slider (red lines as shown in [screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyG2z.png)) but it doesn't get displayed for some reason (I tried writing `<h2>ABCXYZ</h2>` below the `img` tag in every div) but it didn't work. I want it such that it's fixed to its particular slide and moves along with the slides. Can anyone please advise me?

Here's my code:

```
const Row = () => {
    var settings = {
        dots: false,
        autoplay: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
    };
    return (
        
        <Slider {...settings} >
            <div className="slick-list">
                <img src={img1}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="slick-list">
                <img src={img1}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="slick-list">
                <img src={img1}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="slick-list">
                <img src={img1}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="slick-list">
                <img src={img1}></img>
            </div>
        </Slider>
    )
}
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0 6px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.slick-list {
  margin: 0 -6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try adding the text to the :after CSS selector of slick-list